# Can someone show me what a good dependency matrix looks like and specify why?

Tags: java, matrix, dependencies, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I would like to start using DSM, but not sure how to get started.

What does a good dependency matrix look like and why? How does it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On this blog post [Identify Code Structure Patterns with No Effort](https://blog.ndepend.com/identify-net-code-structure-patterns-with-no-effort/) it is explained how to use a Dependency Structure Matrix to identify Code Structure Patterns. The screenshots are done with the [Dependency Structure Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependenciesView) of the tool NDepend. Here are a few patterns:

Layered code (code with no cycle, certainly the coolest thing that a DSM can show you at a glance)
[image]

Code with dependency cycles
[image]

High Cohesion / Low-Coupling
[image]

Hungry Caller 
[image]

Popular Callee
[image]

Mutual Coupling
[image]

Data Object
[image]

Comment: This is really helpful. Unfortunately, the images in the [linked article](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2009/08/24/identify-code-structure-patterns-at-a-glance/) are now missing, and were already missing in the first Wayback capture: https://web.archive.org/web/20110324091932/http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2009/08/24/identify-code-structure-patterns-at-a-glance/

Comment: I don't see any image missing, they are all here well displayed?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I was referring to the missing images on the blog post: [Identify Code Structure Patterns at a Glance](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2009/08/24/identify-code-structure-patterns-at-a-glance/). The images here don't provide the full context, so I was hoping to find out more from the article.

Comment: See also Patrick's newer article https://blog.ndepend.com/identify-net-code-structure-patterns-with-no-effort/ which shares a lot of the same text and images, including some of the images above. (Archived as https://web.archive.org/web/20191003234718/https://blog.ndepend.com/identify-net-code-structure-patterns-with-no-effort/)

Answer (score 3):

[Erik Dörnenburg gives the best description](http://erik.doernenburg.com/2010/04/dependency-structure-matrix/) I've seen, including some good examples of how arrangements of the graph can expose structural issues.  Briefly:

- as others have mentioned, anything above the diagonal indicates a cycle, which essentially means that your boundaries are "fuzzy" (not clean)
- smallish squares (well, lower triangles) along the diagonal == good, if the components are grouped according to hierarchy
- on the other hand, heavily weighted rows or columns == possible issues: either

  - rows: you have a component/group that lots of others depend on (maybe it's trying to serve too many features), or
  - columns: you have a component/group that depends on lots of others (maybe it's trying to take care of everything itself, instead of delegating)

Answer (score 1):

List the subsystems on the X and Y axis in the same order.
Mark an "O" diagonally. Subsystems depending on themselves doesn't
make much sense. Go vertically down the matrix. If that subsystem
depends on the matching horizontal subsystem, mark an X.

A good one rearranges the subsystems to show patterns that might
lead to a good refactoring.

I don't have one handy, though. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most valuable feature of a DSM is to detect cycles, for example between projects or packages. A cycle is displayed in the top-right side of the matrix. 
See this page for more details : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Dependency+Structure+Matrix