# Recommend Source Code Comprehension Tool

Tags: java, dependencies, visualization, dependency-analysis

Do any of you use Source Code Comprehension tools for Java? Can you recommend one? I'm looking for something that visualizes the dependencies between jars/packages/classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various free and commercial tools that generate dependency matrix/summary:

- [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/)
- [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/dependency_analysis.html)
- [JavaDepend](http://www.javadepend.com/)
- [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html)
- [DependencyFinder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/)
- [Structure 101](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/)
- [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.de/uml/neweditions/)

See also:

- [Can someone show me what a good dependency matrix looks like and specify why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535541)

Comment: most UML tools can visualize dependencies I think.

Comment: can i ask here if anyone mind to answer it, my senior said that Sonar an InteliJ is not a code comprehension code instead it is a productivity tools? well i already asked this matter in stackexchange too

Answer (score 2):

Some research tools used in the academia:

- [Javex](http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/javex/index.html) and [LSEdit](http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/lsedit/index.html)
- [Creole](http://www.thechiselgroup.org/creole) and [Shrimp](http://www.thechiselgroup.org/shrimp)

Answer (score 1):

What you request is mainly divided in 2 parts :

- Tools for **jar dependencies** (for example **Maven** and its Eclipse-plugin for graphical dependencies).
- a tool for **classes / packages dependencies** (for example an UML reversing tool).

For the UML tool, check this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u).